# C++: Default values in class member

Tags: c++, class, default, member

I have a problem with specifying the default values for my C++ class members. My code is:

**From Someclass.h:**

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool);
}
```

**...from SomeClass.cpp:**

```
void SomeClass::printOut(bool foobar=true)
{
    if (foobar) { std::cout << foobar << std::endl; }
}
```

**...and finally, from main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    SomeClass s;
    s.printOut();
    return 0;
}
```

This however gives error message (gcc):

```
../main.cpp: In function `int main()':
../main.cpp:8: error: no matching function for call to `SomeClass::printOut()'
../SomeClass.h:18: note: candidates are: void SomeClass::printOut(bool)
subdir.mk:21: recipe for target `main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I have tried specifying the default value directly into the class declaration in the header file, etc. I also tried searching both Stack Overflow and Google in general, but cannot find any solution anywhere. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't specified the default value for the parameter in the header as such, the compiler is looking for a function of signature `void printOut(void)` for your statement `s.printOut();` but correctly not finding it. What you need is:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut( bool fValue = true );  // Note change in param in definition
}
```

And in your cpp :

```
void SomeClass::printOut(bool foobar /*=true*/ )
{
    if (foobar) { std::cout << foobar << std::endl; }
}
```

As a side note, bear in mind you don't have to put the commented out default value for the parameter in the implementation file but it is a good idea for readability.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare the default value inside the class definition, not in the implementation.

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool foobar = true);   //move default here
}

void SomeClass::printOut(bool foobar)     //remove from here
{
    if (foobar) { std::cout << foobar << std::endl; }
}
```

Also, note that:

```
SomeClass s();
```

doesn't do what you expect it to do. It doesn't create an object `s` of type `SomeClass`, but declares a function `s` with return type `SomeClass`. `s.printOut();` shouldn't compile.

You probably want:

```
SomeClass s;
```

Answer (score 1):

Default value must be specified in the declaration of the method, not in the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters must be defined in the header like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool value = true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rewrite as follow .. note bool b=false

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool b=false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify default value in header file:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool foobar=true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the default value has to be specified in the declaration and not in the definition. You can specify default value at both the places but cant omit from definition. hope i dint confuse you. I will show the e\corrected code so you can understand:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();
    void printOut (bool foobar = true);
}
```

...from SomeClass.cpp:

```
void SomeClass::printOut() //or you can use: void SomeClass::printOut(bool foobar=true)
{
    if (foobar) { std::cout << foobar << std::endl; }
}
```

...and finally, from main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    SomeClass s();
    s.printOut();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This won't compile, the signature in your implementation is wrong